# Building J4 fails in github workflow (tarball data for joomla-a11y-checker corrupted)

Tags: joomla-4.x

Upon a few days i was building Joomla 4 in an Github Workflow and after done continued doing other stuff.

Now the build process fails and i dont understand whats going wrong.

**Important: The build needs to happen in the `build/joomla` folder**

Checkout and composer install works.

The simplifield build yml:

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - "*"
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Checkout Joomla 4
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: joomla/joomla-cms
          ref: "4.1.0"
          path: build/joomla

      - name: Composer J4
        run: composer install --working-dir=build/joomla --prefer-dist --ignore-platform-reqs --no-interaction --no-progress --optimize-autoloader --ansi

      - run: npm --prefix build/joomla ci
```

This is the error message:

```
Run npm --prefix build/joomla ci
  npm --prefix build/joomla ci
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
npm WARN tarball tarball data for joomla-a11y-checker@https://github.com/joomla-projects/joomla-a11y-checker/tarball/joomla (sha512-E08QHQBpwkvzSsMweQlO9GmVNkP3dyarJ+bWTXkMDObeqUxAJTZOHZ7o7sQstmWLlJg/Q46OB4Ki76UMaFXzFg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-E08QHQBpwkvzSsMweQlO9GmVNkP3dyarJ+bWTXkMDObeqUxAJTZOHZ7o7sQstmWLlJg/Q46OB4Ki76UMaFXzFg== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-E08QHQBpwkvzSsMweQlO9GmVNkP3dyarJ+bWTXkMDObeqUxAJTZOHZ7o7sQstmWLlJg/Q46OB4Ki76UMaFXzFg== but got sha512-OK88rVpbPI1Q91LY1YzloVOtDgNywCTNWk7vHoVTdA+SALbTw+XhGyNiHKmxrUnwgS6PHKdE3FgO1XU9HI/4uQ==. (3736345 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-02-24T18_42_00_025Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```